# how to choose size of subpieces for sorting with merge sort+insertion sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting

There have been the same question with small differences here, and as I could not find exactly what I wanted I wanted to ask it separately, so my question is as follows:

In "Introduction to Algorithms" by Cormen, section 2, problem 2.1, option d asks that if one wanted to combine merge sort with insertion sort for less timing in practice, as insertion sort can be faster on small size inputs due to smaller coefficient, by dividing the input size of n into k pieces and apply insertion on this small pieces of size n/k, how would one choose k?

My attempt was that consider the worst case for combined sort and best case for normal merge sort, and then find a suitable k as a lower bound, as :
in the worst case,i think, n/k pieces each will require `k^2/2` time (there are additional terms perhaps,but just considering leading coefficients), hence total of nk/2 steps. additionally sorting with merge will require `nlg(n/k)` time, so considering the following :
`nk/2+nlg(n/k)=nlg(n)`, gives `k=2,4` but I have also seen people saying k=10 or 15 are okay, so how could one improve on this?

**NOTE**: 
Sorry for the lack of LATEX style, this is my first time on this site so I will be looking for an edit and suggestion

Comment: Unfortunately, this site doesn' t support $latex$, so don't worry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the answer is highly dependent on the actual implementations of the insertion sort part and the merge sort part, and how their cost compares to the cost of a comparison.

If comparisons are very expensive, for example, then merge sort will be better at any size > 3.

The whole point of asymptotic notation is to be independent of the actual cost of operations, so evaluate the cost of a specific-size merge sort vs a specific-size insertion sort using the asymptotic bound alone.  You need the actual numbers.

The practical way to decide is via experiment over a variety of realistic use cases.  I have heard that best point to switch from *quicksort* to insertion sort is usually around 7 items.  I haven't heard a similar story vs mergesort.